# Send executable jar to hadoop cluster and run as "hadoop jar"

Tags: hadoop, cloud, bigdata

I commonly make a executable jar package with a main method and run by the commandline "hadoop jar Some.jar ClassWithMain input output"

In this main method, Job and Configuration may be configured and Configuration class has a setter to specify mapper or reducer class like conf.setMapperClass(Mapper.class).

However, In the case of submitting job remotely, I should set jar and Mapper or more classes to use hadoop client api.

```
job.setJarByClass(HasMainMethod.class);
job.setMapperClass(Mapper_Class.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reducer_Class.class);
```

I want to programmatically transfer jar in client to remote hadoop cluster and execute this jar like "hadoop jar" command to make main method specify mapper and reducer.

So how can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hadoop` is only a shell script. Eventually, `hadoop jar` will invoke `org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar`. What `hadoop jar` do is helping you set up the `CLASSPATH`. So you can use it directly.

For example,

```
String input = "...";
String output = "...";
org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(
    new String[]{"Some.jar", "ClassWithMain", input, output});
```

However, you need to set the `CLASSPATH` correctly before you use it. A convenient way to get the correct `CLASSPATH` is `hadoop classpath`. Type this command and you will get the full `CLASSPATH`.

Then set up the `CLASSPATH` before you run your java application. For example,

```
export CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath):$CLASSPATH
java -jar YourJar.jar
```

Comment: that's v helpful info.