# Running Hadoop jar command through Java

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, jar, command

I want to run this command in linux through java code. 
I am writing a java code to run all hadoop commands instead of typing one by one.

`hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount input/wordcount.txt output`

I tried **Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)**; it did not work with hadoop.
Also, I tried **ProcessBuilder** and it did not work too.
Is there anyway to run hadoop command through java code ?

Comment: You can try a method explained in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394663/send-executable-jar-to-hadoop-cluster-and-run-as-hadoop-jar
Although it isn't an exact answer to your question but provide a way to use API method to execute jar.

Comment: Could you please post the error you are getting ? Also is there a chance for you to include all those commands in a Shell or batch script and run them.

Comment: Please share the errorlogs. That will help.

Comment: I am  not getting any error. I have to run 10 different commands the first 5 run probably and then when the program reach this command, I am not getting any output the map reduce does not start if I pass this command through java code; however, if I type the command manually in shell, the map reduce runs and I get the expected output. Is there a specific way to run hadoop jar commmand through java? I mean do I need to import any library ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try hadoop jar WordCount.jar ur_pacjage_name.WordCount input/wordcount.txt output

Comment: I am not using any package. If I type the same command manually it works. The problem is not in the command syntax, in java I think.